# How to test my android app's lifecycle?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that creates a static object and then creates a new activity. The second activity accesses the static object in its onCreate() method. When run normally, everything is fine and dandy but if the user leaves the app when it is in the second activity and then goes on with other memory consuming tasks that kill the app (as shown on the left side of the App life-cycle), then upon reopening the app, it is re-created at the second activity but the original static object does not persist. This causes a null point exception in the onCreate() method. Obviously I can put the static object into the save bundle and put it back using the savedInstanceState but I wanted to know how to easily replicate creating an app not on the starting activity because it can take quite some time for the OS to decide to kill it due to memory consumption issues.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One relatively simple way to test it would be to simply send the device an Intent to launch your second Activity.

You can do this using ADB's activity manager (am) command like so:

`adb shell am start -n your.package.name/.YourActivity`

This will launch your second Activity and the application will be in a state similar to as if Android had reclaimed memory your app was using.

Note that you will have to set your Activity to be exported in your manifest for this to work, and you should make sure to change it back after you are done debugging. You can set the Activity as exported like so:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:exported="true" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I get permission denied when I attempt this. I am able to start my first activity this way but not my second. It gives errors and permission denial.

Comment: Ah yes, your Activity needs to be set as exported for this to work. I have updated my answer.